# Compute a percent with Sphinxsearch

Tags: php, sphinx

With [Sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/), how could I display a percent of the keywords matching the results?

For example, I have these two lines in my users table :

```
Paul Smith, Belgium
Maher AbouAbbas, Russian Federation
```

If the query is "Maher Russian Belgium", I want to display :

```
[33%] Paul Smith, Belgium (Belgium matches)
[66%] Maher AbouAbbas, Russian Federation (Maher and Russian matches)
```

Comment: We have no idea... why don't you _try_ to consult their DOCs first?....

Comment: Why would the second example be 100% match? Two out of three terms have exact matches within the phrase. Wouldn't it be a 66% match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rudimentary example that first comes to mind is to simply return the results, then explode them and check each word for words in the query string (also exploded) to compute the percent of words found in the item that are also in the query string.

Comment: Good idea. I'm not going to use Sphinx to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, sir!  I always try to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=827). Maybe that's what you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks, but I have just tried it, and it doesn't seems to be what I'm looking for. With that, I think I'll get 100% if all the words match with the keywords, and that's not what I want. If I enter only a single word wich matches, I want to get 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the Levenshtein string distance algorithm, which is implemented natively in PHP: http://php.net/levenshtein